# why django admin static files doesn't load

Tags: python, django, admin

Since I had started Django, I'm tackling some ridiculous problems. Recently, when I start a new project and I run it on the server, Django's admin CSS is not loaded. The last project I ran on the server, after a while it was okay, and the real Django admin template was there and the CSS was loaded and it was working. But this time again the same problem happened and I don't know how to solve it cause the project [here is the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpVy8.png) is raw, with no special code.
I don't know if it's Chrome problem or not, but I have tried it on other browsers and it was the same thing.

I would be glad if you can help me

Comment: Django does not serve media/static files on production (`DEBUG = False`). You need to configure nginx/apache to serve static/media files there.

Comment: I guess that you do not specify css file path correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer I found was to change `STATIC_URL = 'static/'` in settings.py to `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. Only one '/' may change your whole admin appearance. This problem may not happens to everyone but running code in Pycharm, I had been tackling it for such a long time.

Comment: This answer worked for me in 2023 with django version 4.1 using mysql xamp connection. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If this problem is happening locally, then just change your settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
#...
#...
STATIC_ROOT = YOUR_STATIC_ROOT_DIRECTORY
```

Then run collectstatic, make sure you have a proper `STATIC_ROOT` directory which is also in your `settings.py` file

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

If you have deployed your app on a production server then, you have to follow certain things in order to get stylesheet and javascript files.

**Firstly**
In your `urls.py` you need to add this code

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + \
               static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Then you have to use a third-party media file server(CDN) Like AWS S3 or you can serve your css, js or media files from your Django server
If you don't want to use AWS S3, then you can either send css/js using your django app (which is not ideal to do), or you can use nginx or apachee to send your css/js

**For Nginx to send js/css**
You have to add a Static and Media File Root that can be accessed by your django application, I usually use `/var/www/` to serve static and media from any Linux server

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'var/www/media'
```

Then if you are using nginx

```
server {
    server_name domainname.com;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/static;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /var/www/media;
    }
```

If it is still not working, then your django app might not be able to use the given static_root and media directory, make sure your app has access to them

If you want to send your js/css from your django app (Better not to do in production)
Then

To install `whitenoise`

```
pip install whitenoise
```

In your settings file

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
  # ...
]
```

Comment: Whitenoise is only required when you want to serve your static files through your python application (hint: you don't want that in general). Just run `collectstatic`, set `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT`, and then copy-paste the `location` blocks from the nginx config above.

Comment: Yeah you are right, my bad.

Comment: you know, my project is totally raw! This problem happens whenever I start a new one and the funny thing is that there is no special code and even the static files and folders are not created yet. My main thing is that maybe if I create HTML files and give them a style, it can work but the admin panel is still like what it was, and it's hard to use!

Comment: `urlpatterns += ...` is also only required if serving static files from Django.