# Django admin doesn't load Static files but folder is there in Azure cloud

Tags: javascript, css, django, azure, static

I deployed a Django project in an Azure web App which doesn't load the styles and static files in admin interface.
According to this [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70905685/why-django-admin-static-files-doesnt-load#comment125348415_70905685) Django doesn't serve static files in production (when Debug is false), it suggests to configure the web server to the static files (Apache or Nginx).

The startup script is this:

```bash
    echo "------------------------> Collect static"
    python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput

    # Create database tables
    echo "------------------------- >Start migratons"
    python3 manage.py makemigrations --noinput
    python3 manage.py migrate

    # Start
    python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The static folder is created but not served, when debug is true the static folder loads.

The thing is, how to show the django admin static files in an Azure web App?
Thanks.

Comment: could you please provide the code you tried did you deploy to Azure Web or azure  static Web app

Comment: Added the startup script

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternativas. Normally, you use Nginx + gunicorn, apache/mod_wsgi, (nginx + ) uwsgi or something similar to deploy Django in production. All these allow to serve the static files from the `STATIC_ROOT` folder. Use [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/): `./manage.py collectstatic [--link]` to recollect all statics put them into this folder.

Comment: Thank you Erny, already doing that, the folder is created but not served